# I am getting InvalidValueError in property 'destination' while using directions service

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3

My code is as follows:

```
var initialize = function (data) {
    var directionsDisplay;
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();

    google.maps.visualRefresh = true;
    var centerLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(33.766948, 72.823462);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 5,
        center: centerLocation,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.G_NORMAL_MAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
    directionsDisplay.setOptions({ suppressMarkers: true });
    var request = {
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
    };

    // mark source and destinations
    $.each(data, function (i, item) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            'position': new 
              google.maps.LatLng(item.Latitude,item.Longitude),
            'map': map,
            'title': item.Name
        });

        // 1 means source, 2 means destination, 3 means it is a stop
        if (item.Color == 1) {
            request.origin = marker.getPosition();                
        }
        else if (item.Color == 2) {
            **request.destination = marker.getPosition();**
        }

        directionsService.route(request, function (result, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
            }
        });
    })
}
```

The error I am getting is as follows:

> InvalidValueError: in property destination: not a string; and not a
>   LatLng or LatLngLiteral: not an Object; and not an Object

Comment: You aren't setting `request.destination` (or `request.origin`).  Please provide a [mcve] that exhibits the issue (with sample data that you believe should work).

Answer (score 0):

Just simply get the `directionsService.route(request, function (result, status) {...` outside your `$.each` loop and this should work. Based on the code that you have sent, I am assuming that the `data` object that you're using in your `$.each` looks like this:

```
var data = [
  {Latitude: 39.627012, Longitude: 66.974973, Name: 'Afghanistan', Color: 1},
  {Latitude: 41.444172, Longitude: 74.741835, Name: 'Kyrgyzstan', Color: 2}
];
```

Let me explain to you how your codes inside the `$.each` loop work. The first thing it does is to set a marker:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  'position': new google.maps.LatLng(item.Latitude,item.Longitude),
  'map': map,
  'title': item.Name
});
```

Next is a condition where you determine if the marker is the origin or destination by getting the value of `color`

```
if (item.Color == 1) {
  request.origin = marker.getPosition();
}
else if (item.Color == 2) {
  request.destination = marker.getPosition();
}
```

If you would think of this, you will either get an origin or a destination after 1 loop. Then you will call this code to get the direction:

```
directionsService.route(request, function (result, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
    }
});
```

This part will then trigger an error:

> InvalidValueError: in property destination: not a string; and not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: not an Object; and not an Object

This means that you did not provide a valid destination. If we are going to use the sample `data` object that I have provided above, you can see that the first object is the `origin` since `color: 1`. But destination is not yet set, and only be set after the second loop.

If you move the `directionsService.route(request, function (result, status) {...` outside the loop, the origin and destination will be set first before using the `request` variable in this function.

Your code `$.each` loop should look like this:

```
$.each(data, function (i, item) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      'position': new google.maps.LatLng(item.Latitude,item.Longitude),
      'map': map,
      'title': item.Name
    });
    if (item.Color == 1) {
      request.origin = marker.getPosition();
    }
    else if (item.Color == 2) {
      request.destination = marker.getPosition();
    }
  });
  directionsService.route(request, function (result, status) {
    console.log(status)
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
    }
  });
```

if you want to see this code in action, you may check this link:
http://jsbin.com/lomekek/edit?html,js,output